# Can Android Chrome be linked to an account other than your main Android account?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Say that your main Android account is account1@gmail.com. Can you set up Android Chrome to use account2@gmail.com?

(Ideally Chrome would allow multiple users, which will no doubt happen in Android too eventually.)

Comment: "Use" in what way? For synchronization?

Comment: Yes, in terms of synchronization. I have read in the meantime that under Jelly Bean Chrome has become the default browser for Android, so I very much doubt it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launch Chrome

- In the overflow menu, choose `Settings`
- Under basics, tap the entry for your account
- Disconnect the account; you'll be warned that the data will remain but you'll lose your synchronization
- Tap `Sign in to Chrome` at the bottom of the screen
- Choose the account you want to use for synchronizing

Obviously for this to work you will need to have already added the account to your phone.

Comment: Thanks Al! I don't yet have a 4.x Android device, but this possibility is a must for me. Thanks again.